# How to create a tunnel SSH from my laptop to LXC installing on AWS EC2

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have an EC2 instance on AWS and I installed `LXC/LXD` on my EC2. My `LXD` has a bridge IP address that I need to access via `ssh` from my laptop to the `LXC/LXD`

So if:

```
Me (A) ------> EC2 (B) ------> Target (C)
```

I need to tunnel straight from `(A)` to `(C)`.

Comment: You enabled "GatewayPorts yes" in the sshd?

Comment: What error message? Also you probably need to edit the question to show what config/command line you are using where.

Comment: gatewaports in ec2 machine b or target c ??

Comment: can you tell me how to create an ssh tunnel to get access from machine A to my target C

Comment: My target C is an LXD/LXC with a bridge connexion

Comment: No, Not with out a LOT more information (e.g. is the home machine behind a NAT gateway?) And you need to share the error message and what options you have already tried.

Comment: ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9001:<ip-of-the-container>:22 localhost retur "Bad local forwarding specification '0.0.0.0:9001"

Comment: Me (A) ------> EC2 (B) ------> Target (C), I need to tunnel straight from (A) to (C).

Comment: how can i create this tunnel

Comment: So you've now removed detail from the question rather than adding, making it even harder to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

the tunnel should be established like this:

`ssh -p remote_port -L local_port:target_server:target_port remote_user@remote_server`

- remote_port --> The port of the remote server (in your case EC2 B)
- local_port --> The port in your local machine (in your case YOU A)
- target_port --> The port in your target machine (in your case TARGET C)
- target_server --> Target C
- remote_server --> EC2 B

Try the following:

- in your local PC execute `ssh -p 22 -L 8080:target_server:22 remote_usero@remote_server`
- Then in another window, execute `ssh -p 8080 127.0.0.1`

  With the first connection you open the tunnel. Leave this connection open (to the first server) in order to access the target server from another window.

Comment: how can i choose my local port? what is remote_user@remote_server ?

Comment: Depends what you are trying to achieve. You are trying to access a service in Target C from your local machine, right? What service? Maven? a Web server?

Comment: connexion via ssh

Comment: You have access to server EC2 but target C is only accesible from EC2 but not from your home machine, right?

Comment: yes that's it
i have access from my laptop to ec2 with key.pem. I can access to target C just from EC2

Comment: OK, try the following:

Comment: should i try this ssh -p 22 -L 22:machinec@ipmachinec:22 remote_user@remote_server ?? or change ssh ports on targets?

Comment: Not exacly. Almost. Try this:ssh -p 2222 -L 22:ipmachinec:22 remote_user@remote_server and then from another Window ssh -p 2222 user_machinec127.0.0.1. You have to use another port, you cannot use port 22 for the tunnel. Also no need to specify the machine c user in the tunnel.

Comment: sorry it does'nt work Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: You need to add your public key in the remote server, or specify the user and type the password

Comment: ssh -p 2222 user_machinec@127.0.0.1 --> the @ was missing

Comment: i add my keys
the problem while creating the tunnel

Comment: This means you are using the wrong private key locally or the wrong public key remotely. make sure you have the right keys at both sides. Best is to generate a new private key in your local machine, or just use user/password authentication. For the tunnel you can use user/password authentication, it should work.